# There is a bug in my code and I don't know where!!! [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I am trying to reproduce the results from an [article](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7514994/?section=abstract). But so far I am not being successful. Here is the code I wrote

> **EDIT**: Based on the initial comments of Zizy Archer, the code has been revised.

```
clear;
Nmax        =  30;              % number of rounds
M           =  10000;           % number of simulations
beta0       =  5*10^-6;         % relative clock offset in micro seconds
alpha0      =  1.01;            % relative clock skew
for simN = 1:M

for N  = 1:Nmax

    mean_dly    =  randi([20 50],N,1).*10^-6;         % micro seconds
    stdd_dly    =  randi([1 5],N,1).*10^-6;           % micro seconds

    XpropDly    =  normrnd(mean_dly,stdd_dly,N,1);    % micro seconds
    YpropDly    =  normrnd(mean_dly,stdd_dly,N,1);    % micro seconds
    prcssTme    =  randi([100 500],N,1).*10^-6;       % micro seconds
    T_1         =  (1:N)'*10^-3;                         % milli seconds
    T_2         =  T_1 + XpropDly;                       % milli seconds
    T_3         =  T_2 + prcssTme;                       % milli seconds
    T_4         =  T_3 + YpropDly;                       % milli seconds

    % actual time
    T_2act      =  (T_1 + XpropDly).*alpha0 + beta0;
    T_3act      =  (T_4 - YpropDly).*alpha0 + beta0;

    % equation 13
    A           =  sum(T_2act(1:N) + T_3act(1:N));
    B           =  sum(T_1(1:N) + T_4(1:N));
    C           =  sum((T_2act(1:N) + T_3act(1:N)).^2);
    D           =  sum((T_2act(1:N) + T_3act(1:N)).*(T_1(1:N) + T_4(1:N)));

    % equation 16
    alpha0est(simN,N)     =  (A.^2-C.*Nmax)./(A.*B-D.*Nmax);
    beta0est(simN,N)      =  (B.*C-A.*D)./(2.*(A.*B-D.*Nmax));
end
timestamps            =  [T_1 T_2 T_3 T_4];
clear T_*;
end
% equation 29 and 30
MSE_alpha   =  sum((alpha0est - alpha0).^2)/M;
MSE_beta    =  sum((beta0est - beta0).^2)/M;

figure %2(a)
semilogy(1:Nmax,MSE_beta.*10^12)
xlabel('N');ylabel('MSE of the estimated offset \beta_{0}')
figure %2(b)
semilogy(1:Nmax,MSE_alpha)
xlabel('N');ylabel('MSE of the estimated skew \alpha_{0}')
```

> But this is what I get:

[image]

> **EDIT2**: Snippets were removed.

**Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?**
**Thanking you all in advance.**

Comment: In your code, average and SD of delay are in msec; not µsec.

Comment: @SardarUsama Since I am measuring the time in microseconds, I am representing the µsec as **10^-3**

Comment: @SardarUsama Sorry I meant Since I am measuring the time in **milliseconds**, I am representing the µsec as 10^-3

Comment: @SardarUsama I have tried as you pointed out but I still cannot reproduce the results

Comment: There is no way µsec be represented that way

Comment: @SardarUsama Anyway, to avoid confusion, I have edited the code

Comment: You didn't update the figures according to your edited code. You have added snapshots from the article and didn't even mention which article you're replicating. Add proper references and use suitable title for your question. "What is my mistake" is not a suitable title. Title should represent what you're attempting in your post

Comment: @SardarUsama done.

Comment: @SardarUsama Yes, I took the snapshots because the article is not an open access one and I thought some people may not have access. Anyway I will add the link to the article and revise the question.

Comment: it is not the matter of who has access and who has not. It is the matter of referencing. if you're really a researcher, you must know that. And you still haven't fixed all the points that I mentioned

Comment: @SardarUsama Could you at least suggest a suitable question?

Comment: Do you know what you're implementing? If yes, that's your title

Comment: @SardarUsama Well, the goal is to implement the proposed nanonetwork synchronization scheme presented in the reference. By employing the scheme, we can estimate the clock skew and clock offset. Over several rounds, the MSE between the estimates and the predefined skew and offset should minimize. And this is result shown in the reference, which is what I want to reproduce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time at least try some rudimentary debugging yourself to figure out what could be wrong.
To debug, perhaps print out some variables or plot stuff. Put some conditionals to check if the values are somewhat expected or make no sense. It isn't that hard if you know something is wrong in such a small piece of code (however, if there was no paper you were trying to hit, this bug might have been lurking for a while).

Well, to the step-by-step solution in this case:

What you immediately notice is that if you plot alpha0est or beta0est, your estimate for alpha is systematically too high, at 1.015 instead of 1.01 for the single round case, similar for beta.
Now, what could it be? It obviously isn't noise in signal processing or delays, this one is shown as all this hairy stuff around the mean, you can set all delays to 0 to verify this. So, it has to be something else. 
Looking further, you can notice that this systematic error is decreasing when you increase number of rounds performed, and is gone for full 30 rounds.

So, it has to be something with the number of rounds you are doing. Now try setting N = 10 instead of 30, whoa now 10 round case is fine. And there you have your bug. Equation 13 from the paper - there you have `N` elements summed. Equation 16 similarly multiplies with `N`. This `N` obviously has to be the same number. But as it turns out, in your code it isn't. Equation 13 in your code sums `ROUNDS` cases. Could be 1, could be 30. Equation 16 multiplies with `N` (=30, always).

All this could be easily avoided if you used saner variable names (all-caps, really?). If you used N for number of rounds performed, and maxN as the limit how many rounds you can try doing at maximum, you would easily get it right.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. So, what I have done is I removed the inner for loop so that `A =  sum(T_2act(1:ROUNDS) + T_3act(1:ROUNDS));`  becomes `A =  (T_2act + T_3act);` . The same was applied for `B`,`C`, and `D`. Necessary revisions to the remainder of the code was made too. However, I am still not able to get the desired result. I have debugged it step by step but still cannot figure it out.

Comment: @nashynash Well, yeah, but T_2act still has ROUNDS elements after this change. alpha0est (and beta0est) use N, which is constantly 30.

Comment: Are you implying that T_2act should be a scalar and not a vector?  T_2act is supposed to be changing every round so it makes sense that it is a vector. I am getting lost here.

Comment: @nashynash T_2act is a vector with `ROUNDS` elements, this is all fine. Therefore A, B, C, D all get summation of `ROUNDS` elements. For equation 16, alpha0est and beta0est, calculation uses `N` (=30). This `N` in equation 16 also needs to be `ROUNDS`.

Comment: Ah ha! That was where the problem was. Thank you so much for your time and help.